# Session used in master page is not redirecting

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5, session-variables, session-state

I am trying to check asp Session "login-check" on the master page of my home.aspx page. Basically I want to redirect to the login page (login.aspx) if session value (login-check) is not set.

```
public partial class user : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{   
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (Session["login-check"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

I have worked with this code in the past as well however this time it's not working. Please suggest why this is not working?

I am using asp.net version 4.5.

Comment: this should normally work. what is the error you are getting

Comment: No error is being shwon - I am loading this page directly without setting the session object, hence this page should redirect to login.aspx. But - no error no redirect! :(

Comment: This should not happen. Have you tried clearing your cookies. Session works with the help of cookies. Also please check if you are not setting session variable in your content page.

Comment: Hello @GaganDeep, 

We were right. Today I deleted the entire page, create a new page and wrote the same code. I tried a whole new browse to test and this time it worked. 

Thank you!